# React Native App with Firebase to Control Alexa Devices?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, alexa-skills-kit

I'm wanting to build a smart light that I can control using a React Native Application connected to firebase database. I found many tutorials that use esp8266 modules to control the device (a light in my case).

But I already own smart bulbs that are connected to my Alexa Ecosystem.
Is there any way I can give Alexa the commands to control my bulb directly via my React Native Mobile App (instead of the Alexa App). If so, please guide me a little. Any resources will be a huge help.

So far I only have experience with building React Native Apps. No experience in IOT devices yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Alexa to react on a vocal command, you have to build a custom Alexa skill.

1. You need an amazon account on developer.amazon.com
2. You need to create a skill in the developer console (https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask) where you also configure the language model (on which sentences the skill will react and invoke an intent)
3. You need a backend, which is triggered by the Amazon Alexa Cloud for those intents. There are multiple ways to implement such a backend - but I am not aware if you could run react native app in a container / on a server. I worst case you need to implement the controlling logic of your app on a backend again (https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit & https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/ask-overviews/what-is-the-alexa-skills-kit.html & https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/build/build-your-skill-overview.html)

You can run such a skill in developer mode just for your alexa account and does not need to publish it. If you like to do that, to enable other users you need to think about account management (linking) and maybe then a smart home skill (https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/smart-home-skills & https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/understand-the-smart-home-skill-api.html) is more interesting for you - it is a little bit more complicated in coding, but the language model is handled by Amazon.